# how to I load a pre-batched dataset on pytorch

Tags: pytorch, h5py

I have a huge dataset that cannot be stored in memory so I prebatched it several files how do I make my dataset and data loader class such that load one bath at a time.

- All the files have the same base name and a unique batch number an
- Example file would be called o3_batch_1.hdf5 or o3_batch_2.hdf5 the
- Largest batch number is  o3_batch_102.hdf5

here is what I have tried so far:

would it work?
length would be the total length of the data.

batchNum would be the non-unique number at the end of the file.

base is the common name shared by the file.

class Data(Dataset):

```
# Constructor
def __init__(self, base, batchNum, length):
    name = base + str(batchNum) 
    with h5py.File(name, "r") as f:
        puzz = np.array(f.get('puzzle'))
        sol = np.array(f.get('Sol'))
    self.puzz = torch.from_numpy(puzz)
    self.sol = torch.from_numpy(sol)
    self.len = length
    
# Getter
def __getitem__(self, batchNum, index):    
    return self.puzz[index], self.sol[index]

# Get length
def __len__(self):
    return self.len
```

Comment: Generally this is done by defining a list or dictionary attribute containing your filenames during `__init__` and then loading the appropriate data during `__getitem__` and returning it. You haven't provided details on how your data is stored on disk or the format of your expected output so we can't really provide implementation details.

Comment: thanks that really helped

Answer (score 0):

I think you can iterate over the Index array, and you can get your data through iteration.

Suppose your file is organized in the following manner

```
/yourFileDir 
o3_batch_1.hdf5
o3_batch_2.hdf5
...
o3_batch_102.hdf5
```

And your batch Index is 0,1,2,...,102

```
h5_dir = '/yourFileDir'
for Index in range(103):
    with h5py.File(h5_dir + 'o3_batch_{}'.format(Index), 'r') as f:
         puzz = np.array(f['puzzle'])
         sol = np.array(f['Sol']) # this depends on how you save your data
```